# how do i fix this Switch.pm in @INC

Tags: perl, cpan

I am trying to install NIPE on ubuntu running on my Windows 10 using Windows Subsystems For Linux, I have cloned the file from GitHub and have done some commands which worked, but the command to fully install NIPE ($ perl nipe.pl install) displays this

Can't locate Switch.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Switch module) (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.26.1 /usr/local/share/perl/5.26.1 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.26 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.26 /usr/share/perl/5.26 /usr/local/lib/site_perl /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base) at nipe.pl line 15.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at nipe.pl line 15.

I have tried installing switch but the error remains the same.

Comment: How did you "install switch"?

Comment: By running cpan and then install switch

Comment: What path was Switch installed to? Is it one of the paths listed in the error?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the depot modules, this can be done with:

$ cpan install Switch JSON LWP :: UserAgent

Unfortunately I do not know much about "Windows Subsystems For Linux"